# How to debug sql queries in activerecord-sqlserver-adapter in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord

**If anyone has a couple of free hours (or days) to help me optimise a few calls and want to be paid for it ( i can offer 150USD an hour ) for their help I would really like your help. I'm getting desperate :)**

I've got some sql queries that are quite slow:

```
Panel Load (1075.7ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [panels].* FROM [panels] WHERE [panels].[agglo_code_id] = @0 AND [panels].[environment_id] = @1 AND [panels].[product_id] = @2 AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM campaign_search_panels WHERE campaign_search_panels.panel_id = panels.panel_id AND campaign_search_panels.campaign_id = 32)) AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "AIDAAU_Avails" WHERE "AIDAAU_Avails"."PanelID" = panels.panel_uid AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."TillDate" >= ''08-21-2017'' AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."FromDate" <= ''09-03-2017''))', N'@0 int, @1 int, @2 int', @0 = 24, @1 = 14, @2 = 25  [["agglo_code_id", 24], ["environment_id", "14"], ["product_id", "25"]]
```

I am trying to figure out how to debug this but I can't quite get it right. I would like to perform an explain on it however I can't access the db directly via a sql client as it's locked down to the ip of the server so I am trying to do it via the rails console on the server.

I can do the following (not sure why it runs two queries):

```
irb(main):049:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT [panels].* FROM [panels] WHERE [panels].[agglo_code_id] = 24 AND [panels].[environment_id] = 14 AND [panels].[product_id] = 25 AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM campaign_search_panels WHERE campaign_search_panels.panel_id = panels.panel_id AND campaign_search_panels.campaign_id = 32)) AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "AIDAAU_Avails" WHERE "AIDAAU_Avails"."PanelID" = panels.panel_uid AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."TillDate" >= ''08-21-2017'' AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."FromDate" <= ''09-03-2017''))')
   (47.3ms)  SELECT [panels].* FROM [panels] WHERE [panels].[agglo_code_id] = 24 AND [panels].[environment_id] = 14 AND [panels].[product_id] = 25 AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM campaign_search_panels WHERE campaign_search_panels.panel_id = panels.panel_id AND campaign_search_panels.campaign_id = 32)) AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "AIDAAU_Avails" WHERE "AIDAAU_Avails"."PanelID" = panels.panel_uid AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."TillDate" >= 08-21-2017 AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."FromDate" <= 09-03-2017))
   (47.3ms)  SELECT [panels].* FROM [panels] WHERE [panels].[agglo_code_id] = 24 AND [panels].[environment_id] = 14 AND [panels].[product_id] = 25 AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM campaign_search_panels WHERE campaign_search_panels.panel_id = panels.panel_id AND campaign_search_panels.campaign_id = 32)) AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "AIDAAU_Avails" WHERE "AIDAAU_Avails"."PanelID" = panels.panel_uid AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."TillDate" >= 08-21-2017 AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."FromDate" <= 09-03-2017))
=> 1143
```

and its much faster that the above but is that because I have replaced all the scalar variables or why is it so much faster? Is there any way I can run the query exactly the same? ie:

```
query = <<-SQL 
  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [panels].* FROM [panels] WHERE [panels].[agglo_code_id] = @0 AND [panels].[environment_id] = @1 AND [panels].[product_id] = @2 AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM campaign_search_panels WHERE campaign_search_panels.panel_id = panels.panel_id AND campaign_search_panels.campaign_id = 32)) AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "AIDAAU_Avails" WHERE "AIDAAU_Avails"."PanelID" = panels.panel_uid AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."TillDate" >= ''08-21-2017'' AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."FromDate" <= ''09-03-2017''))', N'@0 int, @1 int, @2 int', @0 = 24, @1 = 14, @2 = 25  [["agglo_code_id", 24], ["environment_id", "14"], ["product_id", "25"]]
SQL
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near '["agglo_code_id", 24'.:
```

any ideas how it can be improved?

Comment: Could be parameter sniffing if you are seeing the same code go quicker when you run it without parameters. Ideally you would need to see the execution plan to determine if that is indeed the case.

Comment: Most probably your plan is cached with other parameters and it is not suitable for your new query. However a tip, you might open the SSH tunel and connect to database using it

Answer (score 0):

Without the execution plan, it will be extremely difficult to diagnose what the exact performance problem is. However, just by looking at your SQL, I see a huge red flag for me that is likely your performance problem.

```
SELECT
    [panels].*
FROM [panels]
WHERE
    [panels].[agglo_code_id] = @0
AND
    [panels].[environment_id] = @1
AND
    [panels].[product_id] = @2
AND
    (
        NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                    FROM campaign_search_panels
                    WHERE
                        campaign_search_panels.panel_id = panels.panel_id
                    AND
                        campaign_search_panels.campaign_id = 32)
    )
AND
    (
        NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                    FROM AIDAAU_Avails
                    WHERE
                        AIDAAU_Avails.PanelID = panels.panel_uid
                    AND
                        AIDAAU_Avails.TillDate >= '08-21-2017'
                    AND
                        AIDAAU_Avails.FromDate <= '09-03-2017')
    )
```

When I extracted your dynamic SQL and made it pretty, I discovered two things that can cause performance problems. First, you have a `SELECT *` which will grab every column from the table, regardless if you need it. You could potentially be slowing yourself down because you are grabbing way more data then you actually need.

The second thing, which is my huge red flag, is you have two `NOT EXISTS` clauses that run SQL queries. Depending on the amount of data between the three tables, this can be a very expensive operation. For every record returned by your main your query, you need to run each of the `NOT EXISTS` queries. That means if the main query returns 100 rows, you have to run 200 additional queries to satisfy your where clause.

To fix this, you should be able replace those `NOT EXISTS` with two `LEFT JOIN`. I can guess on how to do it, but without data to work with, I can't be certain and don't want to give you something that makes things worse.

To give you an idea of performance difference, I had a query doing something similar. It would take 36 hours to run due to the size of the data. I replaced the sub-queries with some sort of `JOIN` and I had it running in less then an hour.

Comment: Hi virusstorm thanks for your help. I've read a few places that not exists should be roughly similar in performance to joins ie http://www.chrislondon.co/joins-vs-subqueries/ but i agree that the double subquery is not ideal.